# What to do for finger swelling?

Tags: guitar

I need info on what leD guitars are doing for Ra swelling of fingers.  I got 2 fingers swollen. Is there a better way to get swelling down?   I'm swimming. Doing ice. Don't want hard rhenotology drugs. I'm also doing hand therapy.   Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: See a doctor. We're musicians not medical practitioners.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not within the purview of musicians.

Comment: What the heck are leD guitars? And Ra swellings? Doctor has the knowledge for the latter.